# open emacs gui through xlaunch from wsl failed

Tags: emacs, xming, vcxsrv

I was able to open emacs with xlaunch, but somehow it stopped working. I am not familiar with xlaunch. How do I debug this problem?

```
Display 172.27.112.1:0 unavailable, simulating -nw
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was able to resolve itself after I update wsl2 packages.